# Material icons not rendering properly in Chrome when local font is installed

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I'm using latest stable version of Google Chrome on ubuntu 16:04. I needed to use some of the local sites which use Kannada fonts. Installed the required fonts from here https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kannada-font-pack/ejfflcimohddeegmgkacpimbecmmjhon . Enabling the extension breaks rendering of the material icons in my browser.

How to get both the icons and fonts working properly?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was install the suitable font in the system, instead of installing fonts on chrome through the google webstore. I uninstalled the extension and after I installed fonts system-wide everything worked fine.